# How Can I Hide a Pie Chart's Slice in HighCharts Without Removing It From the Legend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, charts, highcharts

I've looked everywhere for an answer to this, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

I just want to be able to start a pie chart, using HighCharts, with certain slices hidden (as if they had been "clicked" off in the legend).

I've done this in HighStock and it was a simple matter of:

```
var chart = $("#overallChart").highcharts(); //$("#overallChart") is the div where my HighStock chart is rendered to.
var series = chart.series;

//*****SET DEFAULT STARTING LINES*****//
for (var s = 0; s < series.length; s++) {
    if (s != 1 && s != 2 && s != 3 && s != 4) {
        series[s].hide();
    }
}
//*****set default starting lines*****//
```

And it works, perfectly.

The problem is, when I try to do this in a highcharts "pie" chart, it doesn't work (doesn't error or anything, simply doesn't work).

I assumed it worked the same way as above, since the documentation shows the same `hide()` method (as well as the explanation).  [Highcharts API Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.hide)

Here's my code for the pie chart:

```
var pieChart = $("#overallPie").highcharts(); //$("#overallPie") is the div where my Highcharts chart is rendered to.
var pieSeries = pieChart.series;

//*****SET DEFAULT STARTING SLICES*****//
for (var p = 0; p < pieSeries.length; p++) {
    if (p != 0 && p != 1) {
        pieSeries[p].hide();
    }
}
//*****set default starting slices*****//
```

I guess you have to do this differently in a pie chart? I've seen somewhere that you can redraw the pie chart, but is this really necessary?

Comment: So you want to hide a slice completely and allow the pie to still complete its full rotation?

Comment: Sry, I didn't respond quickly, I posted and had to go to lunch, but now that you've already successfully answered my question, yes I did want it to complete the full rotation. Thanks, again!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313273/pie-chart-custom-legend

How about this ? This is more proper for hide dynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can just use the `visible: false` on your data series.

See [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k946A/1/) here

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. I wonder why they didn't just stick to the `hide()` method here. Perhaps the pie charts behavior is too different and this method was reserved for other chart types. Anyway, thank you so much for your answer, I was literally dumbfounded and was out of things to try or even look up, lol.

Comment: Is there a toggle option like there is for line graphs, using ,show() and .hide() ?